# Why can't I post with Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, post

I have the following code, with `get`, and it works (the Log `Testing here` printed) when I access http://0.0.0.0:3000/send

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyparser.json())

const port = 3000

app.get('/send', (req, res)=>{
    console.log("Testing Here")
})

var server = app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log("listening to port"+port)
})
```

But when I change it to `post` as below

I have the following code, with `get`, and it works (the Log `Testing here` printed) when I access http://0.0.0.0:3000/send

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyparser.json())

const port = 3000

app.post('/send', (req, res)=>{
    console.log("Testing Here")
})

var server = app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log("listening to port"+port)
})
```

When I access http://0.0.0.0:3000/send (in the Chrome browser), it error in the Browser `Cannot GET /send`. The Log (`Testing here`) didn't get logged.

What's wrong?

Comment: if you're using ```form``` element in the browser, please make sure that you've got ```method="POST"``` in it. For example: ```<form method="POST">```

Answer (score 2):

Anything you try from your browser's location bar is necessarily a GET operation, not a POST. To add POST capability to your node - express app you  need to add a post handler, not replace your get handler with a post handler.

Answer (score 1):

When a browser wants to load a web page, it won't perform a POST request; after all that's for getting data from the user to the server. When loading a web page, like here `localhost:3000/send`, the browser GETs that address and displays the HTML it returns. At no point does a POST request get sent by the browser. You could verify that your endpoint here works by using a tool like [curl](https://curl.se/).